# Unload swf movie

Tags: c#, flash

I am able to load a swf file into my C# program via an `axShockwaveFlash` object, but I have to close it by a user button click.
I tried below codes with all possibilities but none of them worked.

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "";  
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = string.Empty;  
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = null;  
axShockwaveFlash1.Playing = false;
```

Do you have any idea howto "unload" a swf file?

Comment: Does the method Stop() not do what you want?

Comment: @Jehof Sorry, but no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the Flash control from the Windows Form controls collection.  Here's how I implement this (the below code is tested and works perfectly):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash axFlash;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        axFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();  
        axFlash.BeginInit();  
        axFlash.Location = new Point(50, 50);  
        axFlash.Name = "Load/unload test";  
        axFlash.TabIndex = 0; 
        axFlash.EndInit(); 
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
        axFlash.BeginInit();
        axFlash.Location = new Point(50, 80);
        axFlash.Name = "Test Movie";
        axFlash.TabIndex = 0;

        axFlash.Size = new Size(640, 480);
        axFlash.EndInit();
        this.Controls.Add(axFlash);
        axFlash.LoadMovie(0, @"C:\Movies\MyMovie.swf");
    }

    private void unloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(axFlash);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at all impossible, actually it is very easy.  This is the one line of code:                              this.Controls.Remove(axFlash);  I was just showing the rest of the code to give a tested example that worked.

Comment: @J.T.Taylor What if I want to get back to the same swf file when I click on some other form ?